# How to disable portmap on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, services

I notice the message:

`Firewall[313] portmap is listening from 0.0.0.0:111 proto=6`

repeated on my logs ever 30 seconds. How can I disable portmap (not using NFS or anything like that so I assume I have no need for it).

I already tried Lingon.app and disabled com.apple.portmap from there, but that didn't help at all as portmap is still running after i rebooted.

What would be the proper way to disable portmap and stop the service without having to reboot on Mac OS X 10.6.

peto

Comment: oops, wrong port 11->111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering for my self:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.portmap.plist
```

seems to do the trick.

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.portmap.plist
```

to get it back if it really is needed, which i doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any StartupItems in :

- /Library/StartupItems
- ~/Library/StartupItems

Port 11 is for [*Active Users*](http://www.auditmypc.com/port/tcp-port-11.asp), do you have any software monitoring users activities ?